# debezium/kafka consume topic from local api

Tags: java, apache-kafka, debezium

I have use this [debezium-examples](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt)

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml up
```

everything is working fine.. but When I try to access localhost:9092 from local system its not accessible but I can access the following

```
http://127.0.0.1:8083/connectors/
```

In docker compose file what I need to enable so that I am able to consume topics from Java Api outside docker.

```
kafka:
image: debezium/kafka:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
ports:
 - 9092:9092
links:
 - zookeeper
environment:
 - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
```

Comment: What is the error message do you see?

Comment: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/moving-from-hibernate-envers-to-debezium-bae4856c0e1b